# Error with installing an old package

Tags: r, package

A co-worked built a model using both an older version of R (3.1.3) and an older version of randomForestSRC (1.6.0). I have R version 3.2.1 and randomForestSRC version 1.6.1. I was able to install an older version of the randomForestSRC package using the function InstallOldPackage from the repmis package using R 3.2.1. However, it turns out I need to use the old version (3.1.3) to be able to work on this project. Unfortunately, after switching to 3.1.3 I am having trouble actually installing the older version of the randomForestSRC package.

Here is the system info:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United     States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods       base     

other attached packages:
[1] repmis_0.4.4          randomForestSRC_1.6.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-47      data.table_1.9.6  digest_0.6.8      httr_1.0.0            magrittr_1.5     
[6] plyr_1.8.3        R.cache_0.10.0    R.methodsS3_1.7.0 R.oo_1.19.0           R.utils_2.1.0    
[11] R6_2.1.1          Rcpp_0.12.1       stringi_1.0-1     stringr_1.0.0       tools_3.1.3
```

This is where I run into the error (I apologize for the large block of text):

```
> library(repmis)
> InstallOldPackages(pkgs = "randomForestSRC",versions = "1.6.0")

trying URL 'http://cran.r-    project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForestSRC/randomForestSRC_1.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 943881 bytes (921 KB)
opened URL
downloaded 921 KB

* installing *source* package 'randomForestSRC' ...
** package 'randomForestSRC' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/Users/baasman/DOCUME~1/R/R-     31~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/baasman/DOCUME~1/R/R-     31~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="randomForestSRC.dll" OBJECTS="bootstrap.o      classification.o dataParser.o entry.o factorOps.o importance.o impute.o     nodeOps.o nrutil.o random.o regression.o rfsrc.o rfsrcUtil.o split.o splitClas.o      splitCustom.o splitRegr.o splitSurv.o splitUspv.o splitUtil.o stack.o      stackOutput.o stackPreDefined.o survival.o survivalE.o termOps.o trace.o tree.o      treeUtil.o"' had status 127
 ERROR: compilation failed for package 'randomForestSRC'
* removing 'C:/Users/baasman/Documents/R/R-3.1.3/library/randomForestSRC'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/baasman/Documents/R/R-    3.1.3/library/randomForestSRC'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date =     TRUE) :
problem copying C:\Users\baasman\Documents\R\R-3.1.3\library\00LOCK-          randomForestSRC\randomForestSRC\libs\x64\randomForestSRC.dll to          C:\Users\baasman\Documents\R\R-        3.1.3\library\randomForestSRC\libs\x64\randomForestSRC.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/Users/baasman/DOCUME~1/R/R-31~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD   INSTALL     -l "C:\Users\baasman\Documents\R\R-3.1.3\library"      "randomForestSRC_1.6.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘randomForestSRC_1.6.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit     status
             pkgs V1
1 randomForestSRC  0
```

Comment: you're installing from source, do you have the tools to do that

Comment: Likely not. What is the right way to avoid installing from the source? I have tried to install the package manually from a local directory but it led to this error message:  package ‘mydir/randomForestSRC-1.6.0’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)" I got the same error when trying it on 3.2.2.

Comment: see #7 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa) that package needs to compile source code so you need to have rtools installed